# OS X Yosemite Xcode update stuck on 'Waiting'

Tags: macbook-pro, mac-appstore, xcode, macos, launchpad

I recently downloaded Yosemite, and I'm trying to update my Xcode. I hit 'Update' in the App Store, and but it's been stuck at 'Waiting' for the past 30 minutes.

[image: As seen in Launchpad]

[image: As seen in the App Store]

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Yeah, a lot of people have been facing this issue. First, [cancel your update](http://jmp.sh/OUgvkqY). (In the AppStore update window hold <kbd>Option</kbd> to show the Cancel button.)

**Now, you can do two things:**

1. Download and install the **[Xcode DMG from here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode)** (if you have an Apple Developer Account)
2. Or try clearing your cache, and restart the download from the app store. You can use third-party apps or enter this command in your terminal:

   `rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/com.apple.appstore"`

Comment: After downloading the DMG Xcode can take a long time to startup because it Gatekeeper seems to check the application for a while, thats what happend to me. source: http://iphonedev.tv/blog/2014/9/8/xcode-6-beta-is-slow-to-open-fix-gate-keeper-slowness-with-the-terminal

Comment: I keep forgetting that you need the <kbd>Option</kbd> to show very useful tools. All I needed to do in my case was cancel the installation and restart it.

Comment: @elhombre - thanks for the warning - getting xcode 7.2 re-installed took hours (literally) using the .dmg - to download and then install. And then there is the need to reinstall plugins, new documentation etc. Not a great user / developer experience when compared with say JetBrains IDE products whose upgrades are generally seamless.

Comment: I'd also recommend using the commandline `softwareupdate` tool instead of using the app store. `softwareupdate --install --all --verbose`

Comment: @onlynone Command line did not work to install Xcode. :(

Comment: In my case it was a 'new purchase' on a new machine running El Cap (rather than an update). Just cancelling and then hitting install did the trick, without clearing the cache.

Comment: @Otávio I also did the cache removal first. The command line was just more reliable for me after that point.

Comment: Well. First try simply moving Xcode from Applications to Trash. Seriously.

Answer (score 17):

Just wait it out. If you attempted a fix listed in another answer here, quit all applications, restart your computer, and when you boot back up, open the app store to the update page, click the update button and forget about it. It took mine about 20 minutes to actually start and move out of "waiting". I read reports that for some people it took about an hour for it to start.

I tried everything else before and was ready to do a full reinstall of xcode. Nothing worked but for me to just wait.

Comment: Just wanted to chime in and say this is what "worked" for me.  I guess the correct answer here in one word is "patience."

Comment: If this is the solution (I am still waiting to see), then the lack of any indication of progress is part of the problem.

Comment: Pro tip if you are impatient and want to see the progress: Open the "Console" application and filter messages for Xcode, a lot of log events regarding the update are written there.

Comment: waiting it out worked for me.  First I signed out of my app store account, then I restarted the mac, then I signed back in after selecting "update".  Waited about 5 minutes and then it changed from "waiting" to "installing"

Comment: @sdenham - actually, it *isn't* making any progress while "Waiting..." is showing. If it was making progress, it would be showing a download progress bar. Whatever it is waiting for, is not happening. For some people, never happens. So one could say that the problem is there is no way for an expert user to ask *what* it is waiting for - which might help us decide what to do about it.

Answer (score 13):

I solved the problem by moving Xcode from my Applications folder to the trash bin. I didn't have an option to cancel the update (all the buttons under Update in the App Store were grayed out for me).

Once I typed in my password to confirm the move, the App Store prompted me to either cancel the update, or delete the app. Opting to delete the app caused the update to start downloading immediately.

Comment: This seems like the most simple solution, and worked for me having tried a bunch of fancier ways.

Answer (score 3):

This simple approach worked for me:
I did not cancel anything, open AppStore and initiate the update (if you haven't done it yet); then click on the "Store" in the top-left menu and choose the following option - "Check for Unfinished Downloads...". Enter your Apple ID and password and you everything will be up and running.

The reason is that XCode does require additional confirmation before download.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This did not work for me.  It may work for others, so I didn't downvote.

Comment: I don't see a "Check for Unfinished Downloads" anywhere (Catalina, 10.15.5)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add another answer here, I had two versions of Xcode in the launchpad. Opening one brought up a dialogue box asking if I would like to "Install additional components", which seems to have fixed it.

Apart from the two copies of Xcode. And now that Xcode is running, the "upgrade" is downloading. See what happens....

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday this happened to me during regular check for updates,
 and between multiple restarts, and removing manifest.plist 
things started working again.

```
rm "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/com.apple.appstore/manifest.plist"
```

( I actually did some renaming to discover that this was the file of interest.

Comment: I think what this answer is adding to the accepted answer, is that the specific file within com.apple.appstore that is relevant is "manifest.plist".

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons for this happening, will explain my scenario.

## Problem (Xcode-Beta):

- I had Xcode and Xcode-beta installed, I deleted Xcode-beta before tapping on Update on the App Store
- Xcode was waiting to install for over 10 min, restart of the Mac didn't help.

## Solution:

- Go to Launchpad and noticed a completely separate app (without an app icon) waiting to install. On the Launchpad, press and hold till the icons wiggle, delete the app that didn't have an icon.
- Go to AppStore and try installing

I understand that this was a specific case, just stating in case somebody faced a similar issue.

Answer (score -1):

This worked perfectly for another App Store download stuck in "waiting".  I quit the App Store, opened Terminal, pasted in code from Sheharyar's post above to clear cache, and pressed Enter.  Restarted App Store and was able to begin my download immediately.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! This doesn't appear to be a standalone answer, and would probably be better as a comment on the previous answer. I know you don't have the points yet to comment, but I've asked someone to come and look at moving it. In the mean time you can see if you can get the points required to comment! Try browsing and see if there are any questions you want to answer or ask.