# App Store using old information after manual XCode upgrade

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, mac-appstore

I'm running Yosemite on a late 2011 MacBook Pro.  I did [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/153864/27707) to upgrade XCode from a downloaded DMG after the App Store repeatedly stalled.

Now XCode is upgraded but the App Store still shows the same version of XCode as available for upgrade.  And there is one further update (a camera raw package) available.  But neither of them will actually update.  App Store stalls repeatedly.

How do I un-hose the App Store?  I'm ideally looking for some command that will cause App Store to reset itself to a clean state, recognize that the latest XCode is installed, and successfully download and update the camera raw and future packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try resetting the Mac App Store.

1. Enable the debug menu and restart the Mac App Store.

   ```
   defaults write com.apple.appstore ShowDebugMenu -bool true
   ```
2. Choose the **Reset Application** option and restart the Mac App Store.

   [image: App Store Debug Menu]

Comment: A cold reboot was also necessary.  Then it showed XCode as upgraded.