# Xcode update 11.1 stuck on MacOS Catalina

Tags: xcode

I’ve been trying to update Xcode and it seems to be stuck after the download. After sitting and waiting for a while, it seems to have restarted the entire process of downloading and updating again. I’ve currently been staring at it stuck the second time around for about 8 minutes. I’ve included a screenshot of what it looks like alongside the console.

Any tips?

[image]

Comment: [OS X Yosemite Xcode update stuck on 'Waiting'](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152934/os-x-yosemite-xcode-update-stuck-on-waiting?rq=1) is old, but has some tips.