# How do I check the memory usage from a certain time in macOs?

Tags: macos, activity-monitor

I had a website which was using massive amounts of memory on my MacBook but I was unable to take  a screenshot of the total memory usage from Activity Monitor to file an issue with the website. Is there any way I can see the log of the Activity Monitor from a specific time?

Comment: Activity Monitor doesn't keep any history.

Comment: I tat menus does hap a graph of memory use over time

Comment: Also, it's most likely to be an issue with Safari itself, rather than the website's code.

Comment: @benwiggy I am using Firefox and its with the [Redux Essential](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic) page. I am not facing any issues with other pages just this one where it is incredibly laggy.

Comment: That page isn't laggy for me on Safari. It's using 'some memory', but not an inordinate amount.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Activity Monitor does not store historic information about memory usages anywhere.

The system also do not by standard log such information into log files or databases or anything like that. So the information you seek is gone now, I'm afraid.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. A program was running. Now it is not running. The user wants to document how much memory it used when it ran. That information is lost. You cannot record it afterwards.

Comment: Thanks I will try checking with Firefox if it is possible as it could be a memory leak from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redo the issue and collect data:

Download Xcode from  https://developer.apple.com

- [OS X Yosemite Xcode update stuck on 'Waiting'](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152934/os-x-yosemite-xcode-update-stuck-on-waiting)

Use Instruments.app with "Activity Monitor" instrument.

- https://help.apple.com/instruments/mac/current/#/devc63117d3

[image]

Choose all processes. Hit the red button to start recording.

[image]

Comment: This won't work at all. You need to do this BEFORE running the program. You cannot do it afterwards.

Comment: well, the user could visit the website again, and record the trace for the whole duration, and upload the stats in the bug report.

Comment: Well, then the user could also just take the screenshot that the original question was about :-)

Answer (score -1):

Could it help you?

```
while sleep 1s; do date; top -l 1 |grep 'PhysMem:'; done > course.log
```

Comment: This shows the memory usage for the current time. Could you change it to show the memory usage over the last day only?

Comment: @yudhiesh No, old data is not recorded and gone